# Number of iterations for Riemans $J(x): O(\log n)$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

[image: Number of iterations before conversion is obtained]

As we know from Riemann (by means of Derbyshire):
$$ \pi(x) = J(x) - \frac{1}{2}J\left(\sqrt{x}\right) -
    \frac{1}{3} J\left(\sqrt[3]{x}\right) - \frac{1}{5} J\left(\sqrt[5]{x}\right) +
    \frac{1}{6} J\left(\sqrt[6]{x}\right) - \frac{1}{7}J\left(\sqrt[7]{x}\right) +
    \frac{1}{10}J\left(\sqrt[10]{x}\right) \ldots
$$
And we recall that $J(x) = 0, x<2$ so we have absolute convergence (for $x>1$).

The question is about the number of terms, as a function $f$ of $x$.  In prose: $f(x)$ is the smallest $i$ that makes $\sqrt[\large i]{x} < 2$.  Please excuse me for not knowing how to state that without using prose.

The figure shows the number of terms, with one logarithmic scale and $f(10^{99})=329$.  On the other hand, $\ln 10^{99}$ is $230$.

The question is: Is $O(f(x)) = \log x$ or above?

From Oslo, Norway

Comment: $$\sqrt[i]{x}<2\iff x<2^i\iff i>\log_2 x\color{gray}{=\frac{\log x}{\log 2}}.$$

Comment: What is $J(x)$?

Comment: @Gary $J(x)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)}$ is Riemann's prime-power counting function  also sometimes referred to as $\Pi(x)$. $J(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \frac{1}{n} \pi(x^\frac{1}{n})$ and Moebius inversion leads to $\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} J(x^\frac{1}{n})$.